# Imprimir los numeros primos en un arreglo en Java. For anidado vs do-while

Tags: java

Tengo un problema el cual consiste en realizar una impresión en consola de todos los números primos contenidos en un arreglo de 100 elementos generados de forma aleatoria en [java](/questions/tagged/java). La pregunta es cuanto sigue: ¿Por qué el tiempo de ejecución en el caso de utilizar un do-while es mucho mayor que en el caso de utilizar 2 ciclos for anidados?

```java
package main;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int aleatorios[]= new int[100];
        for(int n=0; n<aleatorios.length;n++) {
            aleatorios[n] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            System.out.print(aleatorios[n] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        
            
        for(int i=0;i<aleatorios.length;i++) {
            int contador=0;
            for(int o=1;o<=aleatorios[i];o++) {
                if(aleatorios[i] % o == 0) {
                    contador++;
                }           
            }
            if (contador==2) {
                System.out.print(aleatorios[i] + " ");
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println(" + ");
        
        for(int k=0; k<aleatorios.length;k++) {
            int conta=1;
            do {conta++;}while(aleatorios[k]%conta!=0);
            if (conta==aleatorios[k]) System.out.print(aleatorios[k]+ " ");
            else continue;
        }
        System.out.println(" - ");
        
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes lo que se llama un `caso de borde`, que es un caso excepcional que se escapa de la lógica de tu código

**¿En el caso del Do While, qué pasa cuando `aleatorios[k] == 1` ?**

Es decir esto

```
int conta=1;
do 
{
   conta++;
}while(1 % conta != 0);
```

`conta` comienza como `1` pero pasa a `2` antes de ser evualuado por la condición del DoWhile, y sigue incrementando hasta llegar a `2.147.483.647`, luego se desborda y continua como:

- `-2.147.483.648`
- `-2.147.483.647`
- `-2.147.483.646`
- y así hasta llegar a `-1` que es cuando recién cumple la condición del `while`

Una solución simple para es agregar la condición en el While

```
for(int k=0; k<aleatorios.length;k++) {
   int conta=1;
   do {
    conta++;
   }while(aleatorios[k] != 1 && aleatorios[k]%conta!=0);
   if (conta==aleatorios[k]) System.out.print(aleatorios[k]+ " ");
}
```

**Con esta mejora el `While` pasa a ser más rápido ¿Por qué?**

Porque el `While` se detendrá al encontrar un número divisible, no así tus `for`, para equiparar debes utilizar un `break`

```
for(int i=0;i<aleatorios.length;i++) {
    boolean esprimo=true;
    
    //comenzamos en 2, hasta aleatorios[i]-1
    for(int o=2;o<=aleatorios[i]-1;o++) {
        if(aleatorios[i] % o == 0) {
           esprimo=false;
           break; //si ya es divisible, es decir no es primo, detenemos esta iteración
        }
    }
    
    if(esprimo) System.out.print(aleatorios[i] + " ");       
}
```

Por último una manera aun más eficiente es usar el método del cuadrado (no tengo idea como se llama realmente, pero yo le digo así)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   int aleatorios[]= new int[100];
    for(int n=0; n<aleatorios.length;n++) {
        aleatorios[n] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        System.out.print(aleatorios[n]+ " ");    
    }
    System.out.println("");

    for(int i=0;i<aleatorios.length;i++) {
       if (esPrimo(aleatorios[i])) {
              System.out.println(aleatorios[i]);
          }
    }
}

public static boolean esPrimo(int numero) {
    if (numero <= 1) {
        return false;
    }

    //métodos del cuadrado
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= numero; i++) {
        if (numero % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```